# How to use the Principled BSDF shader to create an old-paper-like material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to make an old paper material in Cycles with the Principled shader. 
Something along the lines of the following image, a bit yellowed out and rough, but still whole
[image: Example image]
This paper, in my render, will also have some text I'll overlay on it, as it is written on it.

I did see a few people also asking around for this, but the only material I found for it was not Principled BSDF (as it was made before it was added) and it doesn't fit the rest of my scene because of it.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Any chance You point us to the "old" material which suits but wasnt made using BSDF so we could try "convert" it to your needs? At least we need an image what exactly You want to achieve buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got for you

[image: PaperFinalImage]

[image: NodeSetup]

For the color, I added a noise texture with a color ramp, the right side being a white-ish yellow, the centre-left being a darker yellow. On the very left, I had a dark orange, but this isn't that important. I then plugged the color ramp into the base color of the BSDF Shader.

If you want to add displacement, I used a Mix RGB node to mix a Noise Texture and a Musgrave Texture. I changed the fac of the Mix RGB so it is mostly the Musgrave Texture. When you connect the Mix RGB node to a displacement node, you will want to turn the strength down a lot. I changed the strength to about 0.05 in my example.

That should make a decent old paper texture using the Principled BSDF shader.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you, this suits it perfectly.